# Trouble Centering

Tags: html, css

I'm developing my webpage and I followed this tutorial "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tdRozm__K0". The only thing I am trying to change is centering the text. And I've haven't been able to get it right. It's been close, but my OCD just won't allow it. Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}

.header {
 background: #383838;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 position: fixed;
}

.container {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
 float: center;
 font-size: 15;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <!-- IGNORE THIS! THIS IS FOR LiveReload -->
  <script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
  <!-- IGNORE THIS! THIS IS FOR LiveReload -->
  
  <div class="header">
   
   <div class="container">
    
    <div class="logo">
     <h1>WEBSITE</h1>
    </div>
   
   </div>
  
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fixed width of container, Just remove it and give `text-align:center` to `.logo`.

Check it out:

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}

.header {
 background: #383838;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 position: fixed;
}

.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
 float: center;
 font-size: 15;
 color: white;
    text-align:center;  // Here align center make text center.
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <!-- IGNORE THIS! THIS IS FOR LiveReload -->
  
  <!-- IGNORE THIS! THIS IS FOR LiveReload -->
  
  <div class="header">
   
   <div class="container">
    
    <div class="logo">
     <h1>WEBSITE</h1>
    </div>
   
   </div>
  
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It did! How do I mark as correct? Sorry I just joined tonight.

Comment: I will, It says I have to wait 2 mins.